# Meteor remote ddp connected collection does not allow update operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm currently connecting a Meteor App A to another Meteor App B (where the DB lives) using:

In App A:

```
remote = DDP.connect('http://url.of.app.B');
Booking = new Mongo.Collection('booking', remote);
Booking.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){
    return false
 },
  update: function(userId, doc){
    return true
 },
  remove: function(userId, doc){
   return false
 }
});
```

And have been able to do find operations just fine. But if I'm trying to do an update operation (using a Meteor method call to update on the server-side (App A) :

```
Booking.update({_id: bookingId}, {$set: {arrived: true} });
```

However I keep getting an error log on my App A after the update is called:

> update failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'update'. [403]

Any idea how to fix this? I have already done the allow /deny rules but it is still not working...

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and the allow/deny rules should be implemented on the App B side instead and that would fix the issue like a charm. Hope this would help others who encountered the same problem ;)